# Open camera and library only in landscape mode in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, landscape

I would like to open the camera and library in landscape mode, but I not be able to do it.

Please someone could explain and give me an example.

I have used the below code but seems some code is missing (for instance: import library), I will need a complete example, how I could implement, functions to open library and the camera and save in the camera roll.

```
 override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
        if let connection =  self.previewLayer?.connection  {
            var currentDevice: UIDevice = UIDevice.currentDevice()
            var orientation: UIDeviceOrientation = currentDevice.orientation

        var previewLayerConnection : AVCaptureConnection = connection

        if (previewLayerConnection.supportsVideoOrientation)
        {
            switch (orientation)
            {
            case .Portrait:
                previewLayerConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
                break
            case .LandscapeRight:
                previewLayerConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeLeft
                break
            case .LandscapeLeft:
                previewLayerConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeRight
                break
            case .PortraitUpsideDown:
                previewLayerConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown
                break


            default:
                previewLayerConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
                break
            }
        }                
    }
}
```

Also indicate that I already have some code implemented then 
I find it easier to implement without the use of additional libraries like AVFoundation.

I am currently using this code in order to open library and camera.

```
  @IBAction func openLibrary(sender: AnyObject) {        ///accion del boton Library

    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated:true, completion: nil)

}

@IBAction func openCamera(sender: AnyObject) {        ///accion del boton Camara



    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera



    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated:true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: Sorry but I have the same doubt again and again...
I despair a little because I can not find the solution.

Comment: ok, thanks, I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

in ur app delegate use this function:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> Int {
    if let presentedView = self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController as? CameraViewController {
   //cameraView
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape.rawValue)
        }
    } else {
        //other view
    }
}
```

Swift 2

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if let presentedView = self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController as? YourCameraViewController {
        //cameraView
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape
    } else {
//other view
// return here ur orientation for other view
}
```

}

Comment: I am using lenguaje Swift, I get the error:

 Objective-C method 'application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:' provided by method 'application(_:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:)' conflicts with optional requirement method 'application(_:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:)' in protocol 'UIApplicationDelegate'

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dulthl1qy61prax/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202016-03-22%2015.31.10.png?dl=0

Comment: just call it from intelisens older parameters in older version of swift can be different like strong or weak or this function can return different type like in swift 2.0 its UIInterfaceMask

Comment: From intelisens? I don't understand how to do this.

Comment: The code seems objective C, I am using Swift, xcode 7.2

Comment: Thanks, now I get the error:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ozw1yyo4pikzotx/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202016-03-29%2015.58.56.png?dl=0

Comment: Also I get the error:
Also I get the error when run the application:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3kisscr3ip2731m/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202016-03-29%2017.33.07.png?dl=0